# Am I allowed to use underscores for hostname names?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, linux, static-ip

I am trying to give a hostname along the lines of `PiComputer_User1` however I am encountering the following error:
 `unable to resolve host (hostname) : Name or service not known`

I have added static ip routes and the appropriate hostname to `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`

I am able to ping and connect via ssh using the ip address and routes which I added, however I still get the error whenever I try to install anything

Additionally when I try to use `hostname -i` I get the error `Name or service not known`

In particular I am noticing that if I use `hostname` it returns the hostname as `PiComputerUser1` where there should be an underscore between computer and user

To confirm one more time I am using the correct naming convention in `hosts` and `hostname`

Does anyone know why I am getting errors, and if I am allowed to use underscores in hostnames to begin with? Thank you!

Comment: your question about a Linux computer is off topic here ... this site is for questions that are specific to Raspberry Pi

Comment: Did you reboot after changing the hostname?

Comment: Use a hyphen (`-`) instead of the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The text string in a hostname must be from ASCII characters. It includes the upper or lower case (A to Z or a to z), digits (0 to 9), the dot symbol (.), and the hyphen symbol (-).

NOTE it is inadvisable to edit `/etc/hostname` or `/etc/hosts` manually.
Change using `raspi-config`.

Getting this wrong can cause networking errors on Debian systems (due to attempts to use FQDN).